# no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Object’ and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an array of card objects however I keep getting an error: "no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Object’ and ‘’)". I feel that I'm making an easy mistake but I'm unclear as to what I am doing wrong. Can someone give me any advice?

Deck.cpp

```
Deck::Deck(int maxSize)
{
    //Set Size
    this->maxSize = maxSize;
    temp = 0;
    value = 0;
    next = 0;
    remaining = maxSize;
    //Create array
    //stackData = new int[maxSize];
    stackData[maxSize] = {Cards(1,club), Cards(1,spade), Cards(1,heart), Cards(1,diamond),
        Cards(2,club), Cards(2,spade), Cards(2,heart), Cards(2,diamond),
        Cards(3,club), Cards(3,spade), Cards(3,heart), Cards(3,diamond),
        Cards(4,club), Cards(4,spade), Cards(4,heart), Cards(4,diamond),
        Cards(5,club), Cards(5,spade), Cards(5,heart), Cards(5,diamond),
        Cards(6,club), Cards(6,spade), Cards(6,heart), Cards(6,diamond),
        Cards(7,club), Cards(7,spade), Cards(7,heart), Cards(7,diamond),
        Cards(8,club), Cards(8,spade), Cards(8,heart), Cards(8,diamond),
        Cards(9,club), Cards(9,spade), Cards(9,heart), Cards(9,diamond),
        Cards(10,club), Cards(10,spade), Cards(10,heart), Cards(10,diamond),
        Cards(11,club), Cards(11,spade), Cards(11,heart), Cards(11,diamond),
        Cards(12,club), Cards(12,spade), Cards(12,heart), Cards(12,diamond),
        Cards(13,club), Cards(13,spade), Cards(13,heart), Cards(13,diamond),
        Cards(0, joker)
    }; //Error is here
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
        stackData[i].print();
    }
}
```

Deck.h

```
class Cards;
class Deck
{
private:
    int remaining;
    int maxSize;
    Cards *stackData;
    int top;
    int next;
    int value;
    Cards *temp;
public:
    Deck(int maxSize);
```

Comment: You cannot create array like this. Use `std::vector` (or `std::array`, since `maxsize` seems to be required to be fixed and equal to 53).

Comment: Since `stackData` is a `Cards*`, `stackData[maxSize]` is a `Cards` - or would be, if it existed. (Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays, and you can't assign to arrays.)

Comment: On a side note, don't use plural names, like "cards", for singular things, like one card. You will only confuse yourself and have mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

const string_view suits[]  = { "diamond", "heart", "spade", "club" };

struct Card {
    int number;
    string_view suit;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Card& c) { return o << c.number << '.' << c.suit; };
};

struct Deck {
    std::vector<Card> cards;
    Deck() {
        for( const auto &s : suits ) {
            for (int n = 1; n < 14; ++n ) {
                cards.push_back( Card{n, s} );
            }
        }

        // print()
        std::copy( cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Card>(std::cout, "\n") )  ;
    };
};

int main() {
    Deck d;
}
```

Comment: I had to make my own adjustments (e.g. I did not need the string_view and I kept the print function) to suit the needs of my project but I was able to get my code working as intended with your advice. Thanks.